# Incorrectly detected fakeraid destroyed data during install

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, raid, data-loss

I have attempted to install ubuntu 14.04 on my PC in parallel (dual boot) with windows XP. My PC has 2 SATA disks, one was more-less devoted to the system, second one to data. However, when running ubuntu live CD, these two disks were detected as being in a raid. Overlooking that and finishing the installation, it resulted in the loss of the data on my second disk.

Becoming reconciled with the data loss, I would still like to understand how it could happen, since I have never setup any kind of raid before on that PC (and in windows the disks were working as non-raid). If a fakeraid signature can appear on disks without user action/knowledge (may be already from manufacturer ?), having the fakeraid autodetection (without checking if the disks contents really corresponds to a raid) in the ubuntu installer would look like a quite serious flaw...

Thanks.